# Cannot add text to a td element

Tags: jquery

I need to add text within a `<td>` element. I get the value correctly via AJAX, but I am going round in circles trying to add this to the `<td>` cell.

The `table` is a Startsheet for a golf competition so there are many rows all the same. I select a player using a dropdown list and then an AJAX call gets the player's handicap which I want to insert into next `<td>` cell

```
<tr>
  <td id='firstTeeTime'>
    <input type="time" class="text-center form-control par" name="teetime1" id="teetime1" value=''>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control member" id = "selectedMember" name="member" required>
      <option value="" selected>Select Member..</option>
      <?php  
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT playerId, firstName, surname FROM members WHERE isActive = 1 ORDER BY surname ASC");
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
          echo "<option value=".$row['playerId'].">". $row['firstName']." ". $row['surname']."</option>";
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td class="playingHandicap"></td>
</tr>
```

```js
$('.member').change(function() {
  var selectedMemberID = $(this).val();
  console.log('memberID is ' + selectedMemberID);
  var selectedEventID = $('#selectedEvent').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/getHandicap.php',
    data: { 
      selectedMemberID: selectedMemberID, 
      selectedEventID: selectedEventID
    },      
    datatype: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
      var hcap = $.parseJSON(response);
      //round exact up or down to nearest integer
      var playingHcap = Math.round(hcap);
      console.log('Playing Handicap is ' + playingHcap);

      $(this).closest('tr').find('.playingHandicap').html(playingHcap);
```

Sorry to ask a simple question but have searched around and nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: You're appending `playingHcap` as a string literal. You need to remove the quotes around it to use the value referenced in the variable: `.html(playingHcap);`

Comment: sorry should have removed quotes before asking question, was one of my attempts to get it working......... doesn't work without either

Comment: Console log shows no errors and the ajax response is correct in retrieving the handicap from database, which is why I'm confused!

Comment: I just noticed the issue, it's to do with the scope of `this` within the `success` handler. See my answer below for details. Also note that you could potentially change `datatype: 'text'` to something more robust, but it depends on the format of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly, you were appending `playingHcap` as a string literal. If you want to insert the text held within the value of the variable, remove the quotes around it.

Secondly, `this` within the `success` handler function will not be the element which the `change` event was raised on. You need to store a reference to that element in the scope outside the AJAX request. Try this:

```
$('.member').change(function() {
  var selectedMemberID = $(this).val();
  var selectedEventID = $('#selectedEvent').val();
  var $member = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/getHandicap.php',
    data: { 
      selectedMemberID: selectedMemberID, 
      selectedEventID: selectedEventID
    },      
    datatype: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
      var hcap = $.parseJSON(response);
      var playingHcap = Math.round(hcap);
      $member.closest('tr').find('.playingHandicap').text(playingHcap);
    }
  });
});
```